# Discord JS // Trying to add role by reacting to the message

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js, args

```js
bot.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
  // Define the emoji user add       
  let role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === 'Alerts');
  if (message.channel.name !== 'alerts') return message.reply(':x: You must go to the channel #alerts');
  message.member.addRole(role);
});
```

Thats the part of my bot.js. I want the user to react in a certain channel and receive role Alerts

Answer (score 2):

You haven't really stated what the problem is, what works and what doesn't work but I'll take a wild stab at some parts which catch my eye.

For starters you are calling properties on the variable `message` whilst in the code you supplied, you didn't create/set a variable named `message`. My guess is that you want the message to which a reaction has been added. To do that you have to use the [`MessageReaction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction) parameter which is supplied in the `messageReactionAdd` event as `reaction`.

From there you can replace `message.<something>` with `reaction.message.<something>` everywhere in the code you supplied.

Something also to note is that you add the role Alerts to `message.member`. This won't work how you want it to, since it will give the Alerts role to the author of the original message.

What (I think) you want to do, is fetch the user who just reacted with the emoji and assign them the Alerts role. You'll have to find the member in the guild first and then assign them the Alerts role. To do this you'll have to use the [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) parameter and find the correct [`Member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) because you can't add a role to a User object but you can to a Member object. Below is some code which should hopefully put you on the right track.

```js
// Fetch and store the guild (the server) in which the message was send.
const guild = reaction.message.guild;

const memberWhoReacted = guild.members.find(member => member.id === user.id);

memberWhoReacted.addRole(role);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `message.member` variable despite not defining `message`.

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. You only need 50 rep points to comment under a question - could you move this there?

Answer (score 1):

Any of these methods won't really work in v12 so I updated it for someone else searching.
If you find any mistakes be sure to make me aware of it.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'] }); //partials arent really needed but I woudld reccomend using them because not every reaction is stored in the cache (it's new in v12)
const prefix = "-";

client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.partial) { //this whole section just checks if the reaction is partial
        try {
            await reaction.fetch(); //fetches reaction because not every reaction is stored in the cache
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Fetching message failed: ', error);
            return;
        }
    }
    if (!user.bot) {
        if (reaction.emoji.id == yourEmojID) { //if the user reacted with the right emoji

            const role = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === yourRoleID); //finds role you want to assign (you could also user .name instead of .id)

            const { guild } = reaction.message //store the guild of the reaction in variable

            const member = guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === user.id); //find the member who reacted (because user and member are seperate things)

            member.roles.add(role); //assign selected role to member

        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick answer, though way too late. So I'll be updating the answer with Discord.js v.12.x (or the same as Discord.js Master)

```js
bot.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
 //Filter the reaction
 if (reaction.id === '<The ID of the Reaction>') {
  // Define the emoji user add
  let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === 'Alerts');
  if (message.channel.name !== 'alerts') {
   message.reply(':x: You must go to the channel #alerts');
  } else {
   message.member.addRole(role.id);
  }
 }
});
```