# Discord.js v12 MessageReactionAdd

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm pretty new to javascript and discord.js, can anyone help me and tell me how I can set the role of the user that reacted? I've been having trouble doing this myself.

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
 if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
 if (reaction.message.id === '755695010657206323') {
  switch (reaction.emoji.id) {
   case '753885482298900510':
    break;
  }
 }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord JS // Trying to add role by reacting to the message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59069737/discord-js-trying-to-add-role-by-reacting-to-the-message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `user` object to resolve the member:

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
 if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
 if (reaction.message.id === '755695010657206323') {
  switch (reaction.emoji.id) {
   case '753885482298900510':
    const member = await reaction.message.guild.members.fetch(user.id);
    member.roles.add('ROLE_ID');
    break;
  }
 }
});
```

Comment: Instead of using `guild.members.fetch(user.id)`, you can just write `guild.member(user)`

Comment: If I remember correctly, the member gets cached when reacting.

Comment: Indeed looks like the member object is sent too https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#message-reaction-add-message-reaction-add-event-fields
it's the same (discord.js will use the cache anyway) and to be sure I use fetch almost everywhere

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!
I really appreciate it!